# Is there a way to detect if the Windows OS is a server (2003/2008) or a workstation (XP/Vista/Win7)?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I want to know Win Api to detect the Windows OS is a server (2003/2008) or a workstation (XP/Vista/Win7)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is something like this :

```
OSVERSIONINFOEX osvi;
BOOL bIsWindowsXPorLater;

ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX));
osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX);

GetVersionEx((LPOSVERSIONINFO )&osvi);

if(osvi.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION)
{
    // Workstation
    printf("VER_NT_WORKSTATION.\n");

}
else
{
    // Server
    if(osvi.wProductType == VER_NT_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER)
    {
        printf("DOMAIN_CONTROLLER.\n");
    }

    if(osvi.wProductType == VER_NT_SERVER)
    {
        printf("SERVER.\n");      
    }
}
```

you also need kernel.lib

Answer (score 2):

Call [`GetVersionEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451.aspx) to get the [`OSVERSIONINFOEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724833.aspx) information and test `wProductType`.

Comment: should we use OSVERSIONINFOEX.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION
 and OSVERSIONINFOEX.wProductType != VER_NT_WORKSTATION to differentiate whether it is workstation or server ?

Comment: That is one way to do it, and probably the most straightforward.  Do note the comments in the `GetVersionEx` documentation about the behavior of programs running in compatibility mode.